# Anyone know of simple paint/annotation control for .net?

Tags: .net, annotations, paint

I want a simple reusable control that I can use in a form to view and annotate images.

Example usage:

- I load an image, or paste from clipboard to the control.
- Annotate image, e.g. draw red ring around a feature.
- Perhaps add some text.
- Save image, or copy to clipboard, in chosen format (i.e. so we can compress).

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found [Paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/), but it's a little heavyweight for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use WPF, you can use the InkCanvas for this task. If Windows Forms, you can grab the Tablet PC SDK and use the InkPicture control.